# Clear tail in git pull

Tags: git

I know I can do a shallow clone using git `clone --depth 1 <branch-name> <repository>`.
I know I can pull new changes using `git pull`.

But is there a way to `git pull` while clearing the tail, so in the end I will have only one commit in the filesystem (as if I would do `clone --depth 1` on the new version?

Comment: Do you need anything more than just the snapshot of the repository? Do you need to run any git commands in it? Perhaps downloading just the snapshot would be more suitable for your use case?

Answer (score 4):

`git pull` and `git clone` both implicitly do `git fetch`, which means they both have many of its arguments. The depth is one of them, so `git pull --depth=1` should do it...

Except that only works if the histories overlap, otherwise git says this:

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

This appears to work:

```
git fetch --depth=1 && git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better *not* to use `git pull`. It does nothing that you can't do far better with `git fetch` followed by some disposal command if needed.

Additionally in your case I would also question whether you need a local copy of this branch at all; if you just want to look at it and perhaps form a feature branch from it, just say `git fetch --depth 1` and stop, and now `git switch --detached origin/branchname` and proceed from there.

That way, there is no local `branchname` preserving unwanted commits. (You'll want to say `git branch -D branchname` once to ensure this.)

Comment: The reason I want this operation is to update a running deployment without loosing local changes (config files etc.). The issue is that I have many deployments (one per feature branch) and the repository is already over gigabyte in size.

Comment: What I do is stash or commit to a branch just the config file stuff, so I can restore it easily after every action that might have trounced it. — Believe me, I've been in this situation, I'm sympathetic. I don't see how what you've said negates my suggestion.